# Fatal - Interface not implemented - OkHttp3 - Android

Tags: android, okhttp, rx-android

I am requesting a JSON file with OkHttp3, RetroFit 2.0 + RxObservable and it throws Interface not implemented.  This appears to only happen on Android 4.3 users who are running an older version of our app and upgrade to the latest app version.

```
01-19 16:43:31.089 1611-1692/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[MyDataIntentService]
                                     java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented
                                         at okhttp3.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:100)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.streamFailed(StreamAllocation.java:332)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.recover(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:209)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:132)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                         at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:212)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
                                         at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
                                         at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:179)
                                         at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:63)
                                         at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
                                         at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:144)
                                         at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:125)
                                         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
                                         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                                         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
                                         at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
                                         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8759)
                                         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8726)
                                         at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8581)
                                         at com.somepackage.someclass.loadSomeJSONThing(MyFile.kt:61)
```

---

Here's the call:

```
//get returns Observable<Any>
myApi.getSomeObj("some_id")
     .subscribe({ responseHandler(it) },
                { Crashlytics.logException(it) })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an OkHttp regression. We’re incorrectly assuming `Socket` implements `Closeable`, which isn't the case for older devices. Will fix very soon.

Fixed here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/pull/3125

Comment: For API 16, i do not have the ability to try-catch resource

Comment: @TimNuwin You could not use the snapshot, or you could wait for the next build.